# Interaction between xml file and python script in Ansible

Tags: python, linux, ansible, rhel7

Currently, I have a playbook that creates an .xml file and a python script which takes in the .xml file and processes it. I intend to use use j2 templating to create the file in the form of *{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic_short }}.xml* so that I can keep track of the new files. However right now the playbook is really static as the path is hard coded in the shell command and the python script.

Any suggestions?

```
---
- name: testing
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: execute some shell command that produces an xml output file in current dir
      shell: XXX

    - name: Takes in xml output file produced earlier and passes into script.py 
      script: python_script.py
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: How do I
1) save the xml output file from the shell command for the python script to use 
2) pass the saved output (if possible) into the python script

Comment: Please do not spread the needed info to answer your question over comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: use `chdir` arg to shell so that your command runs in a specified dir and your xmll file is produced there. Edit your python script so it can take an argument to specify the path of the xml file on the target.

Comment: if i understand what you are saying (i hope i got it right), this involves hard coding the path right? in the script - trying to avoid that if possible

Comment: You can give whatever value to chdir, hardoced or not. But you now know where your xml file is. You can then call your script `script: my_python.py -f /path/to/xml/on/target` (argument to your python script you have to add).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, Why not using a shell script that prints on the stdout the XML content, so that you can register it in a variable and use it after with variable.stdout?
Like:

```
- name: generate xml
  shell:
    echo '<xml></xml>'
  register: myxml

- name: create xml file
  copy:
    content: "{{ myxml.stdout }}"
    dest: "{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic_short }}.xml"
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I forgot to specify, the shell command produces an xml file through a specified flag, and the stdout has a format which is different from what I need.

Comment: Ok, but what about a "cat" right after the XML generation in the shell?

Comment: the shell command can only produce a xml file and not a xml output. W/o specifying the flag i get a different form of output

Comment: And this is fine, but if you let your command create the XML (putting every output in /dev/null) and after this, you cat the produced XML, aren't you ok?